# How to get a pseudo-equivalent circuit for a 2N3904 transistor?

Tags: bjt, circuit-design

I'm trying to analyze an FM transmitter circuit, but it has a 2N3904 circuit. I have just basic circuit analysis tools; how could I get a circuit that does similar things to this transistor using just L's, R's, C's and sources? I know I could apply the hybrid-\$\pi\$ model, but I don't know how to get the parameters. Is not for practical purposes, so I don't care about power and frequencies concerns.

Comment: You can't.  A transistor is a current amplifier.  You cannot build an amplifier out of passives.

Comment: Ostensibly, "and sources" includes the not-passive components that would be necessary.

Comment: "I have just basic circuit analysis tools". Get better tools! LTSpice is free; it has a 2N3904 model.

Comment: How do you define "basic circuit analysis tools" in a way that doesn't include a copy of [LTspice](http://www.linear.com/designtools/software/) or even [Berkeley SPICE](http://embedded.eecs.berkeley.edu/pubs/downloads/spice/index.htm)? Both will simulate a small-signal NPN.

Comment: @WarrenYoung Beat you by seconds. :)  Only because I didn't include a link, and mention Berkeley SPICE. :(

Answer (score 1):

One [on-line source](http://www.zen22142.zen.co.uk/Theory/tr_model.htm) and many others have information on the 2N3904 transistor. The one I linked gives pretty good parameters for 2N3904 Hybrid -Pi model.

If you have a spice simulator, try looking for a Spice model for 2N3904.